# React Router Dom v6: Prevent unmounting parent components

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I try to prevent the unmount/rerender of parent components when navigating to another sub route. To achieve this I migrated to v6 since I expected that with the new relative routing this problem would be solved but it's not.

Imagine the following paths:

> example.com/dashboard/data1

> example.com/dashboard/data2

If you navigate from data1 to data2 the Dashboard component will also be rerendered even though nothing changed. How is it possible to prevent this? All parent components should be mounted if a sub route changes.